# Correctly configuring routes or htaccess for laravel in wamp

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, wamp

I'm learning laravel. I using this project https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth

I follow each step without any problem. When it says 'projects root folder' I'm using the same folder and it seems fine.. not sue what it means by 'projects root folder'

The project is located on wamp64/www/jeremy to access it I have to go to localhost/jeremy/public 
Shouldn't it be naturally localhost/jeremy?

And when it read CSS and images it looks for them into localhost/ not localhost/jeremy/public.

I'm not sure what more info I can give and not sure what exactly is the problem.

Comment: https://www.codementor.io/magarrent/how-to-install-laravel-5-xampp-windows-du107u9ji

Comment: Things work better if you create a Virtual Host for each of your projects.See [this answer for help setting that up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)

Answer (score 0):

Projects root folder is the the folder in which you cloned the project into.

Example if ran

`git clone https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth laravel-auth`

That will create the folder `laravel-auth` which has the project in it. That is the projects the root folder.

When developing the project I use Laravel Homestead. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead

I am the project author, let me if you need any help.